# MySQL Select the last N days most active users

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, grafana

I am trying to create SQL that will display my API's X most active users over the last Y days. My goal is to identify bulk users.

User table:

> ```
> |----------|-----------------------|
> | user_id  | etc                   | 
> |----------|-----------------------|
> | 2        |                       |
> | 99       |                       |
> |----------|-----------------------|
> ```

API activity table schema:

```
|----------|-----------------------|
| user_id  | date                  | 
|----------|-----------------------|
| 2        | 2019-11-24 10:01:56   |
| 99       | 2019-11-24 10:01:56   |
| 99       | 2019-11-24 10:30:56   |
| 99       | 2019-11-24 10:30:56   |
| 5        | 2019-11-23 10:30:56   |
| 5        | 2019-11-23 10:30:56   |
| 2        | 2019-11-23 10:01:56   |
|----------|-----------------------|
```

Expected result:

```
|----------|-----------------------|-----------|
| user_id  | date                  | count     |
|----------|-----------------------|-----------|
| 99       | 2019-11-24            | 3         |
| 5        | 2019-11-23            | 2         |
|----------|-----------------------|-----------|
```

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT s.search_date, s.user_id, count(s.user_id)
FROM search s
GROUP BY s.user_id
ORDER BY s.search_date;
```

My query is returning the users total count over all days, with their most recent activity date in the date column.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY here. I think you need to address that problem first and foremost.

Comment: user_id is the primary key on the user table. there is a primary key on the activity table but it's not relevant, so it is not illustrated here.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate by day and user, and then filter on the top user per day with a correlated subquery in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT DATE(s.search_date) search_day, s.user_id, COUNT(*)
FROM search s
GROUP BY DATE(s.search_date), s.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM search s1
    WHERE 
        s1.search_date >= DATE(s.search_date) 
        AND s1.search_date < DATE(s.search_date) + interval 1 day
    GROUP BY s1.user_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
DATE(s.search_date), s.user_id
ORDER BY s.search_day;
```

If you are runing MySQL 8.0, you can use windwo functions for filtering:

```
SELECT search_day, user_id, cnt
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY search_day ORDER BY cnt desc) rn
    FROM (
        SELECT DATE(search_date) search_day, user_id, COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM search
        GROUP BY DATE(search_date), user_id
    ) t
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY search_day;
```

Comment: I expect the first query to work, but within the HAVING clause, there seems to be no knowledge of the outer s.search_date.

Comment: I found this reason for the above, which corrected the problem however the query is long running.
_The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well._

Answer (score 1):

Based off what you have provided, I believe you are looking at the following:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    COUNT(*), 
    CONCAT_WS("-",YEAR(date),MONTH(date),DAY(date)) 
FROM USERS 
GROUP BY user_id, CONCAT_WS("-",YEAR(date),MONTH(date),DAY(date))
```

This will show the usage per person per day. Since you have tagged this with the "Grafana" label, you will want to probably also add in a "where" clause to the end of the query which accepts the Grafana native date function.

Comment: Yes I'll be adding timeFilter once the query is worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent users *per day*, then n MySQL 8+, you can use window functions with aggregation:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT DATE(s.search_date) as search_date,
             s.user_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(s.search_date) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM search s
      WHERE s.search_date >= curdate() - interval <y> day
      GROUP BY DATE(s.search_date), user_id
     ) s
WHERE seqnum = <x>;  -- or however many you want on each day
ORDER BY search_date;
```

If you want the most active users over the entire span, then:

```
select user_id, count(*)
from search s
where search_date >= curdate() - interval <y> day
group by user_id
order by count(*) desc
limit <x>;
```